# Bound parameters in ROracle SELECT statements

Tags: oracle, r

When using `ROracle` in `R`, I want to bind some parameters to data, so I do this:

```
> dbh <- dbConnect('Oracle', 'user/pass@host.com:port/sid')
> st <- dbPrepareStatement(dbh, statement="SELECT x FROM mytab WHERE id=:1",
                           bind="character")
> st <- dbExecStatement(st, data.frame(id=c("9ae", "1f3"), stringsAsFactors=F))
> fetch(st)
    x
0 FOO
```

What's unexpected is that it only uses the *first* row of the data frame to do the `SELECT` (if it were using both rows, I'd get 2 output rows in this case, not 1), contrary to the `ROracle` documentation:

> The object that `dbPrepareStatement`
>   produces is then used together with a
>   `data.frame` (which should agree with
>   the bound specification) in calls to
>   `dbExecStatement` to be executed for
>   each row of the `data.frame`.

Am I doing this wrong, or does the above verbiage perhaps only apply to `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding.

Essentially, your SQL has one bind variable, but you are attempting to bind two values. The second value gets thrown away. Perhaps you can do something similar using an `IN` operator in your SQL.

Comment: What I'm saying is to do one select with the first value, then another select with the second value.  It's a common use case to run one statement with multiple (thousands, perhaps) bound values.

Comment: I understood your intent, but thought you expressed it incorrectly. Sorry, I failed to notice you specified the tag `id` in your data frame. Yes, your data frame has two rows and according to the docs it should execute for each row. Perhaps there is a problem because you didn't specify a `row.names` value in the data frame? Not sure you're going to get this fixed on such an old version of the ROracle package, though.

Comment: I agree - but it's been 1.5 years since I asked this, and I'm no longer at the company with the Oracle db, so it's mostly an academic question at this point. =)