# ROracle Errors When Trying to Use Bound Parameters

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I'm using ROracle on a Win7 machine running the following R version:

*platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32

arch           x86_64

os             mingw32

system         x86_64, mingw32

status

major          3

minor          1.1

year           2014

month          07

day            10

svn rev        66115

language       R

version.string R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
nickname       Sock it to Me*

Eventually, I'm going to move the script to a *nix machine, cron it, and run it with RScript.

I want to do something similar to:
    **select * from tablename where 'thingy' in ('string1','string2')**

This would return two rows with all columns in SQLDeveloper (or Toad, etc).

(Ultimately, I want to pull results from one DB into a single column in a data.frame then use those results to loop through
and pull results from a second db, but I also need to be able to do just this function as well.)

I'm following [the documentation for RORacle from here.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/ROracle.pdf)
I've also looked at this (which didn't get an answer):
[Bound parameters in ROracle SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622375/bound-parameters-in-roracle-select-statements)

When I attempt the query from ROracle, I get two different errors, depending on whether I try a dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().

As background, here are the versions, queries and data I'm using:

> Driver name:            Oracle (OCI)
>  
>   Driver version:         1.1-11 
>  
>   Client version:         11.2.0.3.0

The connection information is standard:

> library(ROracle)
>   ora <- dbDriver("Oracle")
>   dbcon <- dbConnect(ora, username = "username", password = "password", dbname = "dbnamefromTNS")

These two queries return the expected results:
**rs_send <- dbSendQuery(dbcon, "select * from tablename where columname_A = 'thingy' and rownum <= 1000")**
**rs_get <- dbGetQuery(dbcon, "select * from tablename where columname_A = 'thingy' and rownum <= 1000")**

That is to say, 1000 rows from tablename where 'thingy' exists in columnname_A.

I have a data.frame of one column, with two rows.

> my.data = data.frame(RANDOM_STRING = as.character(c('string1', 'string2')))

and str(my.data) returns this:

> str(my.data)
>   'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
>   $ RANDOM_STRING: chr  "string1" "string2"

my attempted queries are:

> **nope <- dbSendQuery(dbcon, "select * from tablename where column_A = 'thingy' and widget_name =:1", data = data.frame(widget_name =my.data$RANDOM_STRING))**

which gives me an error of:
*Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  bind data does not match bind specification*

and

> **not_this_either <- dbGetQuery(dbcon, "select * from tablename where column_A = 'thingy' and widget_name =:1", data = data.frame(widget_name =my.data$RANDOM_STRING))**

which gives me an error of:
*Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  bind data has too many rows*

I'm guessing that my problem is in the data=(widget_name=my.data$RANDOM_STRING) part of the queries, but haven't been able to [rubber duck](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) my way through it.

Also, I'm very curious as to why I get two separate and different errors depending on whether the queries use the send (and fetch later) format or the get format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
It wasn't a problem with Oracle or ROracle (I'd suspected this) but with my R code.
I stumbled over the answer trying to solve another problem. 
[This answer about "dynamic strings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416973/dynamic-string-in-r) was the thing that got me moving towards a solution.
It doesn't fit exactly, but close enough to rubberduck my way to an answer from there.

The trick is to wrap the whole thing in a function and run an ldply on it:

```
library(ROracle)
ora <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(ora, username = "username", password = "password", dbname = "yourdbnamefromTNSlist")

yourdatalist <- c(12345, 23456, 34567)

thisfinallyworks <- function(x) {
    dbGetQuery(con, "select * from YourTableNameHere where YOURCOLUMNNAME = :d", data = x)
}

ldply(yourdatalist, thisfinallyworks)
```

row1 of results where datapoint in YOURCOLUMNNAME = 12345
row2 of results where datapoint in YOURCOLUMNNAME = 23456
row3 of results where datapoint in YOURCOLUMNNAME = 34567
etc

Answer (score 1):

If you like the tidyverse there's a slightly more compact way to achieve the above using purrr

```
library(ROracle)
library(purrr)
ora <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(ora, username = "username", password = "password", dbname = "yourdbnamefromTNSlist")

yourdatalist <- c(12345, 23456, 34567)

output <- map_df(yourdatalist, ~ dbGetQuery(con, "select * from YourTableNameHere where YOURCOLUMNNAME = :d", .x))
```